# I wanted to add an element to my array after sorting the array

Tags: java, collections

Here is my code

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer arr[] = {5,4,3,2,15,8,9};
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(arr);            
        Collections.sort(list);
        System.out.println(list);
        list.add(6);// here I am adding 6 to my array.
        System.out.println(list);
        // Here I should get output as [2,3,4,5,6,8,9,15]
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not adding text to your question that explains your problem? And why would you expect the 6 value to be placed in a sorted position?  You're adding it **after** the sorting is done.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, It was asked in one of the interviews that I faced today, So I got the doubt whether we can add and expect the sorted list.

Comment: So you know your answer. Again please improve the question. Edit it, ask an honest to goodness question that explains your problem. Don't just dump an interview question on this site.

Answer (score 1):

You can't because this declaration :

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
```

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) :

> **Arrays.asList** Returns a **fixed-size list** backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.)
>   This method acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based
>   APIs, in combination with Collection.toArray(). The returned list is
>   serializable and implements RandomAccess.

for that you can't add to this list, even if you try to remove `list.remove(index);` this not work.

---

so to solve your problem you can use :

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();//declare the list
for(Integer i : arr){
    list.add(i);//add element by element to the list
}
```

Or simply you can use :

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr));
//----------------------------------^------------------^
```

Comment: you can add some of my answer to yours if you want. That should form a complete answer.

Comment: ooohhh, thank you @ThijsSteel multiple ideas is better no :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the array to stay sorted, you will have to sort it after each insert.

However, using a binary search, you could also find the index i where the item should be inserted and insert it there using `list.add(i,6)`. Which would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot add, as you are using Arrays.asList(arr);

```
 List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
```

asList returning a fixed-size list, you cannot add any element in that, once the list is formed.
You may get java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 15]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
    at Test.main(Test.java:14)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an element without using a list by using 2 arrays: a source array `src` and a destination array `dest`. The destination array will have one more element than the source one. You simply need to copy all the elements of the source array to the destination, and add your new element. Depends on different requirement of your post title & your post body, I added 2 solutions:

#### Solution 1

This solution add an element to your array **AFTER** sorting the array, as mentioned in the post title. But please notice that the element added is located at the tail of the new array.

```
Integer src[] = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 15, 8, 9 };
Integer dest[] = new Integer[src.length + 1];
Arrays.sort(src);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(src));
// [2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 15]

System.arraycopy(src, 0, dest, 0, src.length);
dest[src.length] = 6;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dest));
// [2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 15, 6]
//                        ^
```

#### Solution 2

This solution add an element to your array **BEFORE** sorting the array. It contains the expected array as mentioned in your code comment in the post body.

```
Integer src[] = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 15, 8, 9 };
Integer dest[] = new Integer[src.length + 1];

System.arraycopy(src, 0, dest, 0, src.length);
dest[src.length] = 6;
Arrays.sort(dest);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dest));
// [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 15]
//              ^
```

---

See also:

- Sorting methods in [Arrays (Java Platform SE 8) - Oracle Help Center](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)
- [`System#arraycopy(Object, int, Object, int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-)